# Filling an array from an API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a beginner in Flutter, and have the below Model,

```
@JsonSerializable()
class ModelSamejt {
  String pid;
  String grp;
  String country;
  String indust;
  String job;
  List<ModelUserGroup> content;


  ModelSamejt(
      {
        required this.pid,
        required this.grp,
        required this.country,
        required this.indust,
        required this.job,
        required this.content,

      });

  factory ModelSamejt.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ModelSamejtFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ModelSamejtToJson(this);
```

I'm receiving this Json from API:

```
[
   {
      "pid":1,
      "grp":"Group1",
      "country":"Egypt",
      "indust":"Information Technology",
      "job":"AP",
      "content":[
         {
            "uid":2,
            "puid":1,
            "avatar":"http"://192.168.39.108/koko/image/user//scaled_dacdd0f1-a6e7-4334-a244-87ee52d233306652023795688525335.jpg,
            "fname":abdo2,
            "lname":"sakre",
            "xp":10
         },
```

And this is the Method used to bring data from API :

```
Future<List<ModelSamejt>> getSamejts(List<ModelSamejt> q) async {
  var request = await Dio().get(Api.baseUrl + Api.api + Api.samejt);
  print(request);
  for (Map<String, dynamic> samejt in request.data) {
    List<ModelUserGroup> mqc = [];
    for (Map<String, dynamic> content in samejt['content']) {
      mqc.add(ModelUserGroup(
          uid: content['uid'],
          puid: content['puid'],
          avatar: content['avatar'],
          fname: content['fname'],
          lname: content['lname'],
          xp: content['xp'],


      ));
    }
    q.add(ModelSamejt(
        pid: samejt['pid'],
        grp: samejt['grp'],
        country: samejt['country'],
        indust: samejt['indust'],
        job: samejt['job'],
        content: mqc));
  }
  return q;
}
```

I'm following a tutorial where the instructor filled a static array of his model with static data as follows. I need to do the same by filling my dynamic data coming from the API into an array. How to do this in Flutter?

```
static List<User> users = [
    User(
      id: 1,
      name: 'John',
      age: 25,
      imageUrls: [
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595623238469-fc58b3839cf6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=755&q=80',
      ],
      jobTitle: 'Job Title Here',
      interests: ['Music', 'Economics', 'Football'],
      bio:
          'Sed ut perspiciatis
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array as non-static variable and access this variable in method where you are handling data from API. Similar like this:

```dart
class SomeClass {
  final users = <User>[];

  Future<void> fillUsers() async {
    users.addAll(await api.fetchUsers()):
  }
}
```

And when you call `fillUsers` method, local variable initialized and you will have a data in it.